# Pandas: Connecting information between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The dataframe `A` contains the information about a trip:

```
Id  Name        StartTime           EndTime
0   201 Car1    2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:43:05
1   205 Car2    2016-01-01 00:10:00 2016-01-01 00:45:05
2   345 Car3    2016-01-01 00:01:00 2016-01-01 00:47:05
3   456 Car2    2016-01-02 00:00:00 2016-01-02 02:45:05
4   432 Car1    2016-01-02 00:00:00 2016-01-02 02:47:05
```

The dataframe `B` contains timestamps during the trip (like a gps).

```
    Name    Timestamp
0   Car1    2016-01-01 00:05:00
1   Car1    2016-01-01 00:05:24
2   Car2    2016-01-01 00:10:04
3   Car3    2016-01-01 00:01:04
4   Car2    2016-01-01 00:10:34
5   Car1    2016-01-01 00:05:54
```

I need to add a column to Dataframe `B` called `Id` which picks up the Id from dataframe `A` based on the name and the start and end-times in frame `A`. Both these dataframes are really large, so I need an efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a situation for the recently added `merge_asof`. That takes the left dataframe (dataframe B  here) and does the following:

> For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the
>   right DataFrame whose 'on' key is less than or equal to the left's
>   key. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

make sure we have timestamp data

```
dfa['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa.StartTime)
dfa['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa.EndTime)
dfb['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dfb.Timestamp)
```

Then sort joining columns

```
dfb = dfb.sort_values('Timestamp')
dfa = dfa.sort_values('StartTime')
```

Perfom asof merge by 'Name'

```
pd.merge_asof(dfb, dfa, left_on='Timestamp', right_on='StartTime', by='Name')
```

Output

```
   Name           Timestamp   Id           StartTime             EndTime
0  Car3 2016-01-01 00:01:04  345 2016-01-01 00:01:00 2016-01-01 00:47:05
1  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:00  201 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:43:05
2  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:24  201 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:43:05
3  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:54  201 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:43:05
4  Car2 2016-01-01 00:10:04  205 2016-01-01 00:10:00 2016-01-01 00:45:05
5  Car2 2016-01-01 00:10:34  205 2016-01-01 00:10:00 2016-01-01 00:45:05
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't seem to have the latest version and it's not easy for me to update it. Is there another way of doing this without using merge_asof.

Comment: pandas does not have conditional joins. You will have to use @jezrael's answer which would potentially not be feasible in many cases. This is why merge_asof was built for situations like yours. It is much, much faster than merging and then filtering. I think your best bet is to update pandas. If you cannot easily update pandas you need to find an environment that allows for this to happen as this is very crucial with fast moving development like the pydata tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with outer join on column `Name`, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last remove columns by `drop`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='outer')
df = df[(df.StartTime <= df.Timestamp) & (df.EndTime >= df.Timestamp)]
df = df.drop(['StartTime','EndTime'], axis=1)
print (df)
     Id  Name           Timestamp
0   201  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:00
1   201  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:24
2   201  Car1 2016-01-01 00:05:54
6   205  Car2 2016-01-01 00:10:04
7   205  Car2 2016-01-01 00:10:34
10  345  Car3 2016-01-01 00:01:04
```

Comment: This answer really serves the purpose. But did you benchmark it? How fast is it? It is clearly mentioned in the original post that there is a need for efficiency. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not very fast. Test another answer if faster.